# program to Roll a dice with picture instead number using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, console.log, dice

I am trying to print out images on the dice, instead of just the number. But when i am using document.write, it just opens a new tab, and shows the picture. What should i use to print it out, with the button i have?

```
<div id="roll-dice">
    <button type="button" value="Trow dice" onclick="rolldice()">Roll dice</button>
    <span id="roll-result"></span>
</div>

var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        if (rollResult == 1) document.write('<img src="1.jpg">');
else if (rollResult == 2) document.write('<img src="2.jpg">');
else if (rollResult == 3) document.write('<img src="3.jpg">');
else if (rollResult == 4) document.write('<img src="4.jpg">');
else if (rollResult == 5) document.write('<img src="5.jpg">');
else  document.write('<img src="6.jpg">');
```

Comment: `document.write('<img src="' + rollResult + '.jpg">');`

Comment: @phuzi It still just opens a new tab..

Comment: That was to remove redundant code rather than writing a bunch of `if ... else` statements.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a picturebox and modify its source**

```
<img src="" id="pic-result"/>
```

javascript code :

```
var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var pic = document.getElementById("pic-result");
 if (rollResult == 1) pic.setAttribute('src', '1.jpg');
else if (rollResult == 2) pic.setAttribute('src', '2.jpg');
else if (rollResult == 3) pic.setAttribute('src', '3.jpg');
else if (rollResult == 4) pic.setAttribute('src', '4.jpg');
else if (rollResult == 5) pic.setAttribute('src', '5.jpg>');
else  pic.setAttribute('src', '6.jpg');
```

Comment: the src you modify is not correct. Either use the source directly ie `"2.jpg"` or create a new element `<img src=".."/>` BUT NOT BOTH. It is wrong

Comment: Thanks pointing it out. I had modified the source code in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with `innerHTML` on `#roll-result`:

```js
var diceResult = document.querySelector('#roll-result');

function rolldice() {
var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
diceResult.innerHTML = '<img src="' + rollResult + '.jpg">';
}
```

```html
<div id="roll-dice">
    <button type="button" value="Trow dice" onclick="rolldice()">Roll dice</button>
    <span id="roll-result"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the innerHTML of a parent element rather than writing the element onto the page:

```
<div id="roll-dice">
    <button type="button" value="Trow dice" onclick="rolldice()">Roll dice</button>
    <span id="roll-result"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var imageContainer = document.getElementById("roll-result");
if (rollResult == 1) imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="1.jpg">';
else if (rollResult == 2) imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="2.jpg">';
else if (rollResult == 3) imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="3.jpg">';
else if (rollResult == 4) imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="4.jpg">';
else if (rollResult == 5) imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="5.jpg">';
else  imageContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="6.jpg">';
```

And you can even bypass all the if statements and just use this code, which does exactly the same thing as the above except it is one line long:

```
document.getElementById("roll-result").innerHTML = '<img src="' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1) + '" />
```

Hopefully this helps!